# Entity Framework Core 5.0 conditional linq expression does not process conditional part

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 5.0 connected to PostrgreSQL 13. I'm trying to conditionally add `OrderBy()` and `Take()` to a query like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople(int age, int limitCount)
{
    IQueryable<Person> peopleQuery = _context.people.Where(p => p.Age == age);

    if (limitCount > 0)
        peopleQuery.OrderBy(p => p.DateAddedUTC).Take(limitCount);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(peopleQuery.ToQueryString());

    return peopleQuery;
}
```

Regardless of `limitCount` value, my results are not limited or ordered; `ToQueryString()` returns:

```
SELECT p.id, P.name, P.age 
FROM people AS p
WHERE (p.age = @__age_0))
```

But if `limitCount > 0`, I want something like this:

```
SELECT p.id, P.name, P.age 
FROM people AS p
WHERE (p.age = @__age_0))
ORDER BY p.date_added_utc
LIMIT @__p_1
```

I thought linq queries were composable like this. I've even tried `ToList()` to see if that fixes it but that changed nothing.

How can I achieve my goal without duplicating code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `if (limitCount > 0)` you need to assign `peopleQuery` like this:

```
peopleQuery = peopleQuery.OrderBy(p => p.DateAddedUTC).Take(limitCount);
```